# Hibernate pagination is not working as expected in a Java program

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to debug the below problem. I have a page that will display all the URL links that is obtained from my table in MySQL. It shows a limit of 10 records per page. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Now the problem here is it's able to show the records but when I click next page(page 2), it doesn't display the records and there's error but doesn't reveal the message and I can't debug it. From what I know, if I added more records to my table, it can display page 2 with no issues but when I tried to go to page 3, the same thing happen and couldn't show the records. Something like below:

[image]

I believe this is some calculation issues but I have no idea what I need to do.

This is basically the method being called every time I "switch" page:

```
urlList = nodeFacade.list_url((pageNo - 1) * pageSize, pageSize, sortName, sortorder);
```

pageNo is always the number of the current page.So if I go to page 2,then `pageNo=2` and pageSize is always `10` definitely. Sortname is basically the name of my column(GenDate) and sortOrder is `DESC`. And below is the method being called:

```
public List<UrllinkEntity> list_url(int offset, int limit, String orderBy, String order) {
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT g FROM UrllinkEntity as g ";

            if (orderBy != null) {
                sql += "order by lower(" + orderBy + ") " + order;
            }

            Query q = em.createQuery(sql);
            q.setFirstResult(offset);

            if (limit != 0) {
                q.setMaxResults(limit);
            }

            List modList = q.getResultList();

            return modList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            msg = CoreUtil.wrapMsg(CoreUtil.FUNC_ERROR,
                    this.getClass().getName(), "list_url", e.getMessage());

            return null;
        }
    }
```

I clearly debug every value and it seems to be able to retrieve the values but not being able to display it. So, is there anything I did wrong?

### Edit

Seems like if I use `(lastpagenumber-1)*pageSize` then it would be able to display every page with no issues,however every page is returning the same 10 records as before so it's still not working.

### Edit

From further studying, it seems like `sortName` is causing the problem. Say I have 144 records in the table. The `sortname` is basically orderBy and I tried using `GenDate` which is a column in that table and it's able to go to page 4 before giving error. I tried changing orderBy to `fileID` another column and it's able to display up to page 13 before encountering the same issue. All in all, there's 15 page to show. So I don't know why is this happening.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that maybe your pageNo is wrong. In hibernate pagination, pageNo should be lastPageNumber.

```
Query selectQuery = session.createQuery("SELECT g FROM UrllinkEntity as g ");
selectQuery.setFirstResult((lastPageNumber - 1) * pageSize);
```

Comment: But I follow other modules of my type and they follow the same coding standard doing my way and the module has no problem to display.For example,displaying all users.

Comment: @Daredevil, I doesn't mean that parameter name, I guess that this method is being receiving wrong pagenumber.

Comment: Okay it doesn't work,I am able to go to every page without error but every page just returns the same 10 records as before

Comment: @Daredevil, I am not sure how frond-end call this method. You can check that code to make sure back-end received correct pagenumber

Comment: I did checked many times because everytime i get to "page 4",it doesn't display and says error(in screenshot). From what i noticed too,if i truncate all the records in my table and add them fresh,it's able to display all the records. Not sure what is happening